# Layout Offcenter From Popup Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have an issue where my layout is off center from the popup. Anyone know why?

```
Builder.load_string("""
<AddNewChangePopup>:
    size_hint: .85, .85
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Submit New Change"
    RelativeLayout:
        x: root.x
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        pos_hint: {"bottom": 1, "left": 1}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
            Rectangle: #woohoo!!!
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                    """)
```

[image]

Comment: what is `AddNewChangePopup`?

Comment: It's just a class that inherits Popup.

Comment: those details you should point out in your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].